# SOAP / REST API for retrieving events from WSO2 BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

Is there is a SOAP / REST API for retrieving events from WSO2 BAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, what you can do is to use a WSO2 DSS (WSO2 Data Services Server) and expose the Cassandra data-source as a service to be consumed by a REST or a SOAP service.

Comment: Interesting. But that will require another component to be setup and maintained. Do you know if there are any plans to surface the BAM data through REST interface?

Comment: Yes its will be available with the new BAM (3.0.0), which is called the Data Analytics Server. This would be available by Mid to End Auguest.

Comment: Yes this will be available with the next version of BAM (3.0.0) which is renamed as Data Analytics Server(DAS). DAS would be available in mid Q3 2015. You can download the milestone 4 release from the following URL https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/sinthuja/DAS3.0/wso2das-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip